# How to get facebook user details using access token

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating an app in facebook and when user enters my app then the authentication will happen and after that i will get the access token and id of user now i want the details of the same user and i have to store that in database .... how to do this
CODE I HAVE TRIED IS

```
 <?php 

     $app_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

     $canvas_page = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";

     $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page)."&scope=email,user_birthday";

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
     //print_r($signed_request);

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 
     //print_r($payload);

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
     //print_r($data);

      if(!isset ($_GET['code'])) {
                        if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
                          echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
                   } else {
                        $accessToken = $data["oauth_token"];

                          echo ("<br/><br/>Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
                   } 
      } else {
          echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $pageUrl . "'</script>");
      }

 ?>
```

Now i want the username and other details in string or array format ...
Please help me....

Comment: Use Facebook PHP-SDK https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using this Graph api :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

You can choose the fields you want returned using the fields query parameter:

https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk) which automatically deal with this situation and sets the access token, or you may manually specify the access token using

> setAccessToken($access_token) method

and pass it your user's access token and make Graph API call using api() method to get data about user. If you want to do away with the SDK then you need to add access token as parameter to Graph API end points.